# Parent class has 26 constructor overloads. How to append a small task to all constuctors, without copy+pasting 26 overloads?

Tags: c++

I want to derive a class from a library for the handy powers of polymorphism. In this case, the parent class is [cv::Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#details) from OpenCV 4.1

In my child class, let's call it SpecialMat, I want to add a simple property which can always be calculated during initialization, no matter which of the 26 constructors of cv::Mat are called. What I would *like* to do is something like the following:

```cpp
class SpecialMat : public cv::Mat
{
    private:
    float my_special_property;
    void thisFunctionAlwaysCalledAfterConstructor() {
        //some constant calculation we can always do at initialization
        my_special_property = this.known_property * this.other_known_property;
    }
};
```

Is there any way to do something like this without overloading all 26 constructors of cv::Mat? Is there perhaps a way to create a constructor like:

```cpp
SpecialMat(AnyArgs args) : Mat(args), my_special_property(/*calculation goes here*/) {}
```

Which would call any of the parent class's constructors?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Someone with more in-depth knowledge might have a direct answer, but is lazy-calculation in the getter for this property feasible for you?

Comment: Perhaps use composition rather than inheritance?

Comment: If you want all those 26 constructors to be callable for your class, you have to override (not "overload") all of them anyway, don't you? By the way, `this.known_property` doesn't work in C++. You need `this -> known_property` (or just `known_property`).

Comment: 26! Blimey. They went a bit overkill huh

Comment: @TonyK Neither override nor overload is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variadic template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int i) {}
    Foo(double d, int i) {}
    Foo(const Foo& f) {}
    Foo(char&& c) {}
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    Bar(Args&&... args) 
    :Foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
        ExtraFunc();
    }

private:
    void ExtraFunc() {
        std::cout << "Calculating extra value\n";
    }
};

void Test() {
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0;
    Foo f{i};

    Bar{i};
    Bar{d, i};
    Bar{f};
    Bar('a');
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vDboZK)

Comment: you need to use [perfect forwarding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) here: [example of possible compilation error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0Vxnbw1inuMz0SVb)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I don't like about this solution is that the code completion hints in my text editor (vscode) won't suggest constructor parameters from the base class. Oh well.

Comment: I think the option suggested by @Nowine would probably work better, and doesn't have that issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define a constructor which take the cv::Mat as argument :

```
class SpecialMat : public cv::Mat
{
public:

    SpecialMat(const cv::Mat& mat) :
        Mat{ mat }
        {
            special_func();
        }

    // Optional, can perform better in some cases. See move semantics if 
    // you're not aware of the concept.

    SpecialMat(cv::Mat&& mat) :
        Mat{ std::move(mat) }
        {
            special_func();
        }

private:

    void special_func(void)
    {

    }
};
```

This way, the class cv::Mat is implicitly convertible to SimpleMat :

```
void f(const SpecialMat& mat)
{
    // do some stuff
}

int main(void)
{
    cv::Mat m{};
    f(m);

    SpecialMat m2 = cv::Mat{};
    f(m2);

    return 0;
}
```